# Fetch 2 columns from table into assoc array php

Tags: php, mysql, row, fetch

I have a table with 2 columns

first column is a file id (varchar)

second is date (varchar)

I want to fetch these 2 columns  for each record in my table and stick it in a assoc array

I am aiming to put the file id as the key and the date as the value

I am a bit stuck at the moment, as I am changing my code from an indexed array to a assoc array.

here is what I have so far.

```
function getLiveList(){
    $idQuery = "SELECT file_id FROM live_list";
    $dateQuery = "SELECT date FROM live_list";

    $fileid = mysql_query($idQuery);
    $date = mysql_query($dateQuery); 

    $array = array();


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($date)){
        $array[$row] = $date;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

I know this is wrong but I am on the correct lines im sure!

Here is my error: Warning: Illegal offset type in...

Comment: Refer to the PHP manual, it's very useful and the code samples will get you moving in the right direction. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 3):

First, use `mysqli`:

```
$Link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");
$Query = "SELECT file_id, date FROM live_list";
$Result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)){
    $array[$row['file_id']] = $row['date'];
}
return $array;
```

You don't need to duplicate the query for each column, they can be returned in the same query. Each time a row is fetched `$row` is an associative array with the columns as the keys.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function getLiveList()
 {
        $idQuery = "SELECT file_id FROM live_list";
        $dateQuery = "SELECT date FROM live_list";

        $fileid = mysql_query($idQuery);
        $date = mysql_query($dateQuery); 
        $dates = mysql_fetch_array($date);
        $array = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fileid))
        {
         $array[$row['file_id']] = $dates['date'];
        }
    return $array;
 }
```